# Initialising variable in initState

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm initialising a variable in `initState(){}`:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    getDataFromFirestore();
    super.initState();

    });
  }
```

The method is asyn and basically gets data from Firestore to populate an object '_markerMap' with data. This property is then used as a property in a widget. And this widget is called in my `build` method.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: MyWidget(
            markerMap: _markerMap)
     );
  ....
 }
```

MyWidget is a calendar. markerMaps adds icons to certain dates on the calendar. The markers are only sometimes added to the calendar. So the failure is intermittent. Is is safe to assume that in `initState()`  the data will load from firestore to initialise the variable from Firestore. Any thoughts what might be happening and why only sometimes the markers show up on the calendar?

**adding code where _markerMap is set**

```
getDataFromFirestore() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      Firestore.instance.collection('availableDates').where('bandId', isEqualTo: user.uid).snapshots().listen(
              (data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) => _markerMap.add(
              doc['availableDates'].toDate(),
              Event(
                  date:doc['availableDates'].toDate(),
                  title: 'hello',
                  icon: _presentIcon(doc['availableDates'].toDate().day.toString())))));
      setState(() {});
    }).catchError((onError){
    });
  }
```

Comment: please post some code on how exactly you set `_markerMap` variable.

Comment: Just edited question and added code where _markerMap is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your `getDataFromFirestore` method, you perform the widget rebuild (`setState` call) right after you get the User object (`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` call).

However, you modify `_markerMap` variable later on - only when your `Firestore.instance.collection` query is complete. In this case `setState` call where it is right now is redundant.

Calling `setState` inside of your `listen` callback should solve the problem.

e.g.

```dart
final _markerMap = {};

getDataFromFirestore() async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
    Firestore.instance
      .collection('availableDates')
      .where('bandId', isEqualTo: user.uid)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) {
        setState(() { // Here is the setState call
          _markerMap.add(
            doc['availableDates'].toDate(),
            Event(
              date: doc['availableDates'].toDate(),
              title: 'hello',
              icon: _presentIcon(doc['availableDates'].toDate().day.toString())
            )
          );
        });
      }));
  }).catchError((onError) {});
}
```

*Please double check this example code. My general advice is correct, however I did not test this on my end.*

Comment: Just noticed that for even better results you can move the `setState` one level up - resulting in wrapped `forEach`. e.g. `setState(() { data.documents.forEach(...); });`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with initializing variables in initState unless they are static. So whats happening is you have declared _markerMap initially but it will only get initialed after some async function getDataFromFirestore(), which could take few seconds. And here you have assigned `markerMap: _markerMap` but initially _markerMap is null and only get initialed after getDataFromFirestore() function. Therefore its a good practice to either check for null

```
_markerMap!=null?MyWidget(
            markerMap: _markerMap):Container();
```

or provide a default value

Comment: How can I make sure that _markerMap is not null and the build only called after _markerMap fetches the values from Firestore

Comment: _markerMap!=null?MyWidget(
            markerMap: _markerMap):Container();

Comment: instead of empty container in code you can put circular progress bar or some loader so that will show till you get data

Comment: You could also store the Future from the getDataFromFirestore call and use a FutureBuilder